# Install customplot on python 3.5

Tags: python, matplotlib

Faced the below error when I import customplot on pycharm (python 3.5)
Tried import sipdistutils as well on command prompt but no distribution is found.

Collecting qcustomplot
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/72/a0/d19d35b39b89deca725a5ebcdd0ecfdca358dd17225e6e13a1c7d36c4ec0/qcustomplot-1.3.1-1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\WickedWitch\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\qcustomplot\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sipdistutils import build_ext
ImportError: No module named 'sipdistutils'

----------------------------------------
```

> Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\WickedWitch\AppData\Local\Temp\pycharm-packaging\qcustomplot\